# How to create sap.ui.mdc.table.TreeTable using oData v4 in SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5, metadata, sap-fiori

We have a requirement to create a smart tree table but since the data source is OData v4, we need to make use of SAP.UI.MDC library.

In the existing sample provided by SAP, it makes use of JSONPropertyInfo for Metadata, but in this case the metadata will be coming from the OData v4. So not sure how to make use of it in the Delegate file.

Looking forward for some help from the community if anyone has implemented these kind of requirement.

Below is the reference method provided by SAP for extracting the metadata annotations from the JSONPropertyinfo.js file.
We want to make use of the OData v4 metadata directly

```
const _createColumn = (sId, oPropertyInfo) => {
    const sPropertyName = oPropertyInfo.name;
    return new Column(sId, {
        propertyKey: sPropertyName,
        header: oPropertyInfo.label,
        template: new Text({
            text: {
                path: "mountains>" + sPropertyName,
                type: oPropertyInfo.dataType
            }
        })
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the use case of ODataV4  and TreeTable can be implemented with the help of https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.TreeTable%23overview. Try to bind it to desired entity via rows https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.TreeTable%23aggregations . Further you will need to parse annotations for your entity in order to display correct labels, columns and etc.

See as well https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.AggregationBindingInfo.

Example:

XML Fragment

```
<table:TreeTable id="yourTable">
</table:TreeTable>
```

Controller code

```
const table = <get your table>;
table.bindRows(<AggregationBindingInfo for your table>);
await fetchAnnotations4Table();
parseAnnotations2BuildColumns&More();
```